# Azure Front Door - How to disable Web APP accessible directly to be accessed directly

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I have configured Front door and hosted 2 web apps (Main site and one failover website) in different zone. The web apps has there own URL which are accessible directly. I want these URL should not be accessible directly. It should be accessible through front door only. Please let me know how it can be achieved?

Thanks in advance
-Rajesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to set up Azure App Service access restrictions. See here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions

PS : it also contains a section on how to only allow Front Door access  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#restrict-access-to-a-specific-azure-front-door-instance

Comment: Thanks Rimaz, I tried the steps "Restrict access to a specific Azure Front Door instance". So it blocks the direct access to Web app, but it also block the access through frontdoor also, as frontdoor redirect internally to web app URL which is blocked to be directly access through internet.

Comment: Thanks Rimaz, it worked! It was issue in my web app settings in frontdoor.